# pyqt: unable to find QtCoremod.sip

Tags: python, pyqt, python-sip

I'm building a project that depends on pyqt (e.g. VTK with pyqt).  I'm getting an error like `QtCoremod.sip: No such file` (or something similar).  What's going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu, package  python-qt4-dev was missing. I installed it and it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused if you have multiple installations of sip on your system and the pyqt configure script found the wrong one.  It searches your `$PATH` environment variable to locate sip, and that determines where to place the sip output files for pyqt.

One solution is to manually specify the sip installation locations via options to the pyqt configure.py script.  (That is, `./configure.py --sip=[...] --sip-incdir=[...] --sipdir=[...]` etc.)

Another option is to make sure that your intended `python` and `sip` binaries are found on your `$PATH` before any others that may exist on your system.  Make sure your PATH is set correctly.

For details, see the pyqt installation documentation:
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Years later, same problem, Ubuntu 20.04, but the file is now called,

```
pyqt5-dev
```

> In Ubuntu, package python-qt4-dev was missing. I installed it and it
> fixes the problem.